# Doctrine2 mappings across bundles possible?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to have a OneToOne mapping from an Entity in one Bundle to an Entity in another. I have:

```
# KWI\SeniorProjectBundle\Entity\Project:
use KWI\PeopleBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\KWI\PeopleBundle\Entity\User")
 */
protected $mentor;
```

Yet running `doctrine:schema:update` gives the following error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Class KWI\PeopleBundle\Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Both entities reside in *different* databases (realized through two separate entity managers which use two separate DB connections).

Is this even possible to accomplish? I have the feeling that it's actually pretty common to have different databases that have mappings between each other. So this should be possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Doctrine doesn't seem to support mappings across databases.* Moving both entities into the same entity manager resolves the issue.

Comment: how about if i just want to re-generate the schema or mappings as in when making schema changes?  Now when you either try to update force the doctrine schema or  also when dumping sql there is a trickling effect of errors on ManyToMany relationships. Your saying run that Entity on one side(defined in one controller only), and call it from the other?  E.g. generate evertying on both sides, except filter that fk table on one or the other sides?

Comment: during generation is what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `\` from the class path in `targetEntity="\KWI\PeopleBundle\Entity\User"`, so it looks like `targetEntity="KWI\PeopleBundle\Entity\User"`.

Comment: That's odd, because I get the same error if I preface it with a `\\`.